# Maven's Plugins & Dependencies vs SBT's

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I am having trouble understanding SBT plugins and dependencies. I think I've finally understood Maven's version of those terms, but wanted to know about the similarities and differences of those terms in SBT versus Maven. It's easy to convert Maven deendencies to SBT dependencies (just syntax) so is it also true for plugins?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting dependencies is pretty simple as you've noted - as this is just another syntax for the same artifacts (jars).

The matter around plug-ins is a little different - the principle is the same, extensions of the build with additional capabilities but since maven and sbt are two different build systems the plugins are different and you'd have to search for alternatives with same capabilities rather than somehow use the same